# setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay

Tags: ios, autolayout, setneedsdisplay

What is the real difference between `UIView` methods `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay`?

As usual documentation is foggy about this.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Actually the documentation is pretty clear about this:

- [setNeedsLayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW28) will layout subviews

  > Call this method on your application’s main thread when you want to adjust the layout of a view’s subviews.
- [setNeedsDisplay](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCADHC) will call for a redraw of your view (`drawRect:`, etc).

  > You can use this method or the setNeedsDisplayInRect: to notify the system that your view’s contents need to be redrawn.

Comment: no, I was wondering more in terms of both are used to redraw the view, right? Both will wait until the next draw cycle to be redrawn, right?

Comment: Layout is not about drawing. Layout is about positioning/sizing subviews. But yes, both delay to the next runloop cycle. So calling one multiple times in a row will only result in one relayout/redraw.

Comment: Please provide an example of when `setNeedsDisplay` is needed.

Comment: Call `setNeedsDisplay` to make sure your view redraws itself. A common use case is to call this after changing a property of your class that's used during drawing.

Comment: @Pwner Say you want to draw a line between two dots (two UIView, exactly), this is implemented in `drawRect:` of **DrawLineView**. After you change the position of one button or both of them, you need to call `[drawLineView setNeedsDisplay];` to redraw the line between new position of the two dots.

Comment: @Pwner http://blog.fujianjin6471.com/2015/06/11/An-example-of-when-should-setNeedsDisplay-be-called.html