# UITableView update not removing section headers

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit

I have a tableview which, when displaying more than X items, displays section headers:

[image: 30]

When I delete the last item to go below X (and therefore remove the section headers), the header view heights get updated correctly but the views themselves are left sticking:

[image: withoutheaders]

As soon as I start scrolling the tableview, they go away.

Any idea on how to fix this? (calling `reloadData` obviously does, but seems like a nasty and unnecessarily expensive solution).

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling [setNeedsLayout or setNeedsDisplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506968/setneedslayout-and-setneedsdisplay) to trigger the redrawing of the sub views?

Comment: Of the section header views? Why would I do that? The views are returned by `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` (which I'm making return `nil` when my dataSource.count < X)

Comment: Of the `tableView` so it redraws without the header which you've set to nil. The scroll event is triggering the redraw which makes it go away.

Comment: Neither `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsLayout` seems to fix my issue. Wonder what else the scroll event is triggering that makes them go away...

Comment: @samvermette were you able to fix the issue?