# How to trigger tableView's heightForRowAtIndexPath after viewDidLayoutSubviews get called?

Tags: ios, uitableview, layoutsubviews

`tableViewCell` contains viewController which height is calculated after tableView finish laying out views. So I need to trigger `tableView` to request again height of rows by calling `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

I have tried `setNeedsLayout`, it does not work, system will not call `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

`reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is not good choice, because it will reload all the cells, and all the viewControllers built into the cells, and again when the viewController will finished layout process and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called, `reloadData`  will called again, so it is an infinite loop.

I was testing `tableView.beginUpdates() tableView.endUpdates()` empty update operation. Sometimes it triggers `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is part of the protocol `UITableViewDelegate` and gets called when you perform:
`[tableView reloadData];`

`setNeedsLayout` is a method of `UIView` and causes the view to redraw itself, but it won't trigger a `tableView` to update itself.

Comment: if there are only certain cells that you want to update, you can use `(void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths               withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`. but you'll have to call either of those if you want the height of your row to change... :/

Comment: Can you show some code, maybe that'll help. If you run in an infinite loop by calling `reloadData` it sounds like there might be an issue with your code somewhere, maybe I can help out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can test the setNeedsDisplay in the UIView, this will redraw the view .But the setNeedsLayout is use to layout the subviews (position and size ). If redrawing, the size will re get from the function of delegate.

see
[setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506968/setneedslayout-and-setneedsdisplay)