# What does cell.layoutifneeded and cell.layoutSubviews and cell.setneedsdisplay method do in general?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

What does `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` and `cell.layoutSubviews()` and `cell.setNeedsDisplay()` method do in general ?

Comment: In general, this community helps with specific programming problem, not a broad understanding. You need to read docs for that

Comment: Plz go through this site https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell

Comment: Please refer link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506968/setneedslayout-and-setneedsdisplay

Comment: You can watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjArhdrqAn8 to clarify all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. layoutSubviews

Lays out subviews. in short this method lets determine the size and position of any subviews, it also helps to get desired behaviour you want for your view if your have a subclass. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews)

2.layoutIfNeeded

Forces view to layout immediately,for example you have changed a constraints constant and to reflect the change you need to call layoutIfNeeded.(it can also be animated :P). [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded)

3. setNeedsDisplay

Marks the view need to be redrawn in the next drawing cycle, when you call this method, system is notified that view's content is changed and it will be redrawn in next drawing cycle. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622601-setneedslayout)

Please consider reading documentation for better understanding